# Migrate Wordpress from GCP to Lightsail

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, migrate, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to migrate my Wordpress from localhost to Lightsail but I am suffering some problems. Error 403, console not working,...random things.

In case something like this happened, as a back-up plan I thought of migrating it to GCP instead, because of the free 300$, and after some months, migrate it again to Lightsail.

I have been checking both the docs and the internet searching for a step-by-step guide to make sure that in some months I will be able to do it without any problems, but I haven't found anything at all.

Has anybody migrated in the past a website/wordpress from GCP to Lightsail?

Comment: There are WordPress Plugins to export/import WordPress. I use All In One that works well. https://servmask.com/

Answer (score 0):

From official [AWS](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/migrate-your-wordpress-blog-to-amazon-lightsail) and [Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-wordpress/) documentation all you have to do is export and import your WordPress content

Comment: Finally I was able to set up the Lightsail instance and I won't be needing to migrate from GCP to Lightsail in the future. Nevertheless, coming back to your answer, I read somewhere that GCP blocks the export of the database (whatever that means) and that's why I was asking.    Thanks for the answer

Comment: @AdrianInfante - Google does not block exporting the database. For WordPress the database is MySQL. You can easily export the database using `mysqldump`.